# How should I get started with LEGO trains?

Tags: trains, power-functions

I'd like to get started with LEGO Train. I understand the PF system is The Way, and the tracks are generally mutually compatible, but the exact interplay of trains & power components eludes me.

Is there a "Just the train, PF control system, and tracks" set available?
Would that be [set 60051](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/High-speed-Passenger-Train-60051)?

Answer (score 2):

That set would work, set [60052](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Cargo-Train-60052) would work as well (although it has a few more parts that are not actually needed if you are really focused on trains, in that regard [60098](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Heavy-Haul-Train-60098) might be better)

Those sets (including 60051) are from 2014/2015, rumours have it that new trains will come out this year (probably around august), and apparently (I hadn't heard it before @TheBrickBlogger wrote it in a comment here) they won't be completely compatible.

Comment: I would add to this that the PF system is getting updated this year. The 2018 trains use blutooth connection instead of infrared like the current PF trains. It might be worth waiting a few months until it becomes clear of what the new PF system looks like and its compatibility with the current system, before investing in the current version. There are also a lot of train accessory packs coming with a good mix of tracks, and other components later this year.

Comment: @thebrickblogger when you say accessories, you mean..? Can you aim me at a preview? I don't want to buy into something that will be hard to deal with in a few years.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give you a direct link as the original source has been already taken down, but if you do a search on the 2018 trains, you should be able to find at least some of the upcoming train sets and accessory packs via secondary sources. I would suggest to wait until the sets get released later this year to know for sure how it is compatible with the current PF system. I believe they are summer releases, so we only have to wait a few more months. And we will likely get more details even before the official release date.